# Getting a JavaScript command to run before the function has completed?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide a button when a function starts & show some text & then hide the text & reshow the button when the function completes.

I am having a hard time doing this because of the way JavaScript works in that it doesn't output anything to the screen until the whole function has been completed; hence what I'm trying to do isn't working.

I tried using two different functions on the "onclick" command but this produced the same result.

Can anyone that has more knowledge with JavaScript please tell me how I can achieve what I am trying to do here?

**Edit:** tried the below suggested code:

```
function addCatsSIC2() {

    var addBtnWrapper = document.getElementById('addBtnWrapper');
    var addWait = document.getElementById('addWait');    

    addBtnWrapper.style.display = 'none';
    addWait.style.display = 'block';    

    setTimeout(function(){
        addCatsSIC();
    }, 10);

    addWait.style.display = 'none';
    addBtnWrapper.style.display = 'block';    

}
```

Didn't work. Only difference was that the button I clicked didn't "stay pressed down" until the function completed.

Comment: what are you doing inside the function?

Comment: It depends - jQuery does have a `delay()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
// disable the button
setTimeout(function(){
   // do your actions
   // re-enable the button
}, 10);
```

That ought to give the action a chance to complete, the DOM action will take effect, then timeout function will execute. JS doesn't have threads but this might achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your app.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `setTimout(func, 10)` to run main portion of the function - this way UI update will happen before main code runs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the lines that change the UI to the timer function:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
   addCatsSIC();
   addWait.style.display = 'none';
   addBtnWrapper.style.display = 'block';
}, 10);
```

Otherwise it will get executed before your `addCatsSIC` function.

Comment: Woops.. my bad. I didn't pay enough attention to where I placed the reshowing of the button. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers @Brett please accept Jim or Alexei answers as they gave the correct idea, I just gave a nudge. :)